# How to print "at" inside php date function?

Tags: php

i tried using `date("F j, Y \a\t h:i a", strtotime($date));`

but this produces `May 20, 2013 a 04:37 pm`

i also tried `date("F j, Y \at\ h:i a", strtotime($date));` **and**

```
date("F j, Y \a\t\ h:i a", strtotime($date));
```

and it became `May 20, 2013 a31 04:37 pm`

what i want to produce is this `May 20, 2013 at 04:37 pm`

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your format string in single quotes rather than double quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With double quotes `\t` will be interpreted as a tab character. Using single quotes (or double slashes) takes care of the issue:

```
echo date('F j, Y \a\t h:i a', strtotime('2013-05-20 23:59:59'));
// output: May 20, 2013 at 11:59 pm
```

Comment: 10 more minutes before i can accept this as an answer. thanks! :)